# Automate find and replace

Tags: autocmd, replace, command, find

When having selected something in visual mode where I want to perform a find-and-replace I always have to run `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g` manually. Is there some way so that I can bind it to some key combination that I have to press whilst in visual mode, so that the command automatically appears with the cursor at `s/[cursor here]` and when I press tab the cursor jumps to `s/foo/[jump here]`?

Comment: You might be interested in `<C-r><C-w>` and `<C-r><C-a>` on the `:` command-line, to insert the word (WORD) under the cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first demand you can create a mapping in visual mode.

e.g.:

```
vnoremap s :s/
```

In visual mode if you hit `s` it will make sure the command line is filled with:  `:'<,'>s/`

For the second demand it is unclear how you want foo to be discovered or is it a constant `foo`.

Remark: If you already searched for `foo` in the previous search you could also have:

```
:'<,'>s//bar
```

as equivalent as:

```
:'<,'>s/foo/bar
```

Comment: I don't want it to be discovered, I want that the cursor jumps to the position where I would write the word I want to replace and then jumps to the position where I write the word I want to replace it with

Comment: With my proposition you would: 1. hit `s`, 2. type your word (e.g. `foo`), 3. type `/` (instead of `<tab>`) and 4. type the replacing word (e.g. `bar`). Would that fit the bill?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot!