# Use *-like command in normal mode to execute a find/replace

Tags: normal-mode, replace, find, search-replace

## Background

It's nice to be able to type `*` in normal mode and automatically have Vim search for the word under the cursor.

## Question

Is there an analogous command for executing a find/replace?

E.g. the cursor is on "the" and the result is `:%s/\<the\>/` so that I can easily type `the only/g` for the full find/replace command `:%s/\<the\>/the only/g`.

## Update/clarification

I have learned from a comment on [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37931/automate-find-and-replace) that a solution might involve, to quote that comment,

> `<C-r><C-w>` and `<C-r><C-a>` on the `:` command-line to insert the word (respectively the WORD) under the cursor.

This certainly works and could be used to write a custom command to do what I am asking (e.g., `nnoremap ** :%s/<c-r><c-w>`).

Is that the best way to do this? Or is there a native Vim command that already does what I am looking for?

Comment: I believe that's the best way to do it (`:nnoremap <leader>s :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/`) (or alternatively, `<C-r><C-a>` to use `WORD`)

Comment: An alternative way is to do your search first (using `*`) and then do your replace without search pattern `:%s//the only/g` it will default to the previous search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the replace in two steps:

1. You prepare a search command using `*` (`/\<the\>`)
2. You do your replace with an empty search (`:%s//the only/g`)

The replace will default the search to the last one.

It has the advantage over the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> trick that the word boundary are included in the search.

This way you can test your search before you use it for doing the replacement which I like.

Answer (score 3):

One nice version of this is `*cgn` `replacement`<kbd>Esc</kbd>. This is repeatable with `.`, or `n.` to see what will change before changing it (kind of like `/gc` flags for `:substitute`). If you wanted to do a global replacement for sure, the tricks with `:%substitute/<C-r><C-w>/…/…` are better, but you could also use the `cgn` command with (*e.g.*) `9999.`.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but I don't quite understand your answer. In particular, what is `*cgn`? (I tried `:help *cgn` and `:help cgn`, but nothing came up.) And what role does the Escape key play in the solution?

Comment: @AlexRoberts try `:help gn`, which selects or operates on the next match. So `cgn` changes the next match (like `ciw`; it leaves you in Insert mode, so Escape is necessary to "end" the edit by returning to Normal mode). Then `*cgn` is the same but after searching for the word under the cursor, so that `gn` selects matches for the same word. I encourage you to try it out. The important property is that sequences `<operator>gn` are repeatable for any search pattern

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. That does seem very useful, especially the `.`-repeatability, as you say. And now I understand what you meant by `9999.`; that should usually be enough to do the trick!